# AtomicIntegerArray vs AtomicInteger[]

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic-values

Is there any difference in meaning of `AtomicIntegerArray` and `AtomicInteger[]`?
And which one is faster to use?
(only thing that I noticed is that first is taking much less space, but that means that each recheck is checking boundaries of array, so that would make it slower?)

Edit: In a scenario where array is pre-initialized.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`AtomicInteger[]` will require an object per element. `AtomicIntegerArray` just requires the `AtomicIntegerArray` object and an array object. So use the latter if possible.

The cost of bounds checking is quite small even for normal arrays. What might be significant is that access to data in the same cache line from multiple processors can cause significant performance issues. Therefore separate objects, or deliberately avoiding close elements of an array, can help.

Comment: Who cares about bounds checks? If you look at the (apparent) source code for, say, getAndSet it does the address calculation for both the get and the compareAndSet (although worse than this, most processors can do get-and-set without cas).

Comment: tnx (didn't see your second paragraph there)
So it might be good not to create all objects at the same time? (or with some random order?)

Comment: (I did a quick edit.) Creating objects at different times wont help as the GC will rearrange them. One of the classes in java.util.concurrent goes as far as to add lots of padding (in recent versions). It should be easier and clearer to add padding elements to AtomicIntegerArray, just shift left.

Answer (score 7):

- AtomicInteger[] is an array of thread safe integers.
- AtomicIntegerArray is a thread-safe array of integers.

Comment: That is not true. volatile int[] would be a thread-safe array of integers

Comment: No, it is not a thread-safe array of integers. You only protect the access to the variable covering the reference and ensure you get a fresh copy with a refresh of the data too. Period. Access to the content of the array is neither synchronized or thread-safe or memory-safe after you access the reference for the first time.

Comment: @PostSelf `volatile int[]`  just makes the reference of the array volatile, not its elements. The array elements are not thread safe but the array reference is.

Comment: @yessure I guess it is the limitations of the English language because that is exactly what I meant. So `AtomicIntegerArray` is an array with thread-safe operations and thread-safe access to its elements but not thread-safe access to the array itself (by which I mean the reference)

Answer (score 2):

Underneath, AtomicInteger and AtomicIntegerArray typically use the same low level APIs to perform reads, writes and other CAS operations. (For example, OpenSDK 7 uses `sun.misc.Unsafe` to perform the CAS operations in both classes.) So there is little performance benefit in using AtomicInteger[]. As you've already noted, the use of AtomicIntegerArray *does* have significant memory advantages.

On a practical note, the use of the later frees you from having to construct all your AtomicInteger instances, too. Remember that you cannot naively allocate those lazily due to concurrency reasons; you will have to pre-allocate or use some safe publishing mechanism. So in addition to memory advantages, your code is cleaner.

On a similar vein, if you have a bunch of objects with AtomicInteger members, for example:

```
class ReadCounter {
  private final String _fileName;
  private final AtomicInteger _readCount;
  ...
}

private final Map<String, ReadCounter> _counterByName = ...;
```

Then you can achieve similar memory improvements by modeling the member variable `_readCount` as a `volatile int` and using [`AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.html).

Comment: At the price of lower speed for updater operations (although get and set are fast). Sometimes it's worth extending from Atomic* as a memory saving hack.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Tom Hawtin's first paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/692687/7769052)…

> `AtomicInteger[]` will require an object per element. `AtomicIntegerArray` just requires the `AtomicIntegerArray` object and an array object. So use the latter if possible.

…but it should also be noted that `AtomicInteger[]` is not thread safe.  Specifically, the array's references to the individual `AtomicInteger` objects may or may not be correct if accessed from multiple threads.  Synchronizing access on the array object itself will eliminate this issue, though.

Comment: The point about Atomic* is that you avoid synchronisation. The assumed method of use of an AtomicInteger[] is to create all the AtomicIntegers once and only then publish the array safely.

Comment: I agree.  I'm not advocating using AtomicInteger[], just noting the difference, which is what the question was about :)